# Provided region_name '"$region"' doesn't match a supported format for Windows (CMD)

Tags: docker, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

> I am trying to deploy ECS using Terraform and it's throwing the above error while I am Provisioning the ECR this is happening. It tried removing the double quotes, then enabled trace for troubleshooting. I tried updating to the latest version of terraform as well (v 1.1.2)

**Here is the code chunk from main.tf file**

```
# Inherit configuration from CLI tools.  No nice way to pull in the region from ~/.aws/config

provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
  profile = var.profile
}

resource "null_resource" "push" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
aws ecr get-login-password --region "$region" | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin "$ecr_fqdn"
docker tag "servian/techchallengeapp:latest" "$repository"
docker push "$repository:latest"
docker logout "$ecr_fqdn"
EOF

    environment = {
      ecr_fqdn = regex("^([^/]*)/", aws_ecr_repository.ecs.repository_url).0
      region = var.region
      repository = aws_ecr_repository.ecs.repository_url
    }
  }
  depends_on = [aws_ecr_repository.ecs]
}
```

**The code chunk from the variable.tf file**

```
variable "region" {
     description = "Region to deploy app"
     default = "ap-southeast-2"
   }
```

**Please find the error below**

```
null_resource.push: Creating...
2022-01-04T13:50:08.315+1100 [INFO]  Starting apply for null_resource.push
2022-01-04T13:50:08.315+1100 [DEBUG] null_resource.push: applying the planned Create change
2022-01-04T13:50:08.315+1100 [TRACE] GRPCProvider: ApplyResourceChange
2022-01-04T13:50:08.315+1100 [TRACE] NodeAbstractResouceInstance.writeResourceInstanceState to workingState for null_resource.push
2022-01-04T13:50:08.315+1100 [TRACE] NodeAbstractResouceInstance.writeResourceInstanceState: writing state object for null_resource.push
2022-01-04T13:50:08.315+1100 [TRACE] applyProvisioners: provisioning null_resource.push with "local-exec"
null_resource.push: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.push (local-exec): Executing: ["cmd" "/C" "aws ecr get-login-password --region \"$region\" | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin \"$ecr_fqdn\"\r\ndocker tag \"servian/techchallengeapp:latest\" \"$repository\"\r\ndocker push \"$repository:latest\"\r\ndocker logout \"$ecr_fqdn\"\r\n"]

null_resource.push (local-exec): **Provided region_name '"$region"' doesn't match a supported format.**
null_resource.push (local-exec): Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
2022-01-04T13:50:09.038+1100 [WARN]  Errors while provisioning null_resource.push with "local-exec", so aborting
2022-01-04T13:50:09.038+1100 [TRACE] evalApplyProvisioners: null_resource.push provisioning failed, but we will continue anyway at the caller's request
2022-01-04T13:50:09.038+1100 [TRACE] maybeTainted: null_resource.push encountered an error during creation, so it is now marked as tainted
2022-01-04T13:50:09.038+1100 [TRACE] NodeAbstractResouceInstance.writeResourceInstanceState to workingState for null_resource.push
2022-01-04T13:50:09.038+1100 [TRACE] NodeAbstractResouceInstance.writeResourceInstanceState: writing state object for null_resource.push
2022-01-04T13:50:09.038+1100 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: have already backed up original terraform.tfstate to terraform.tfstate.backup on a previous write
2022-01-04T13:50:09.040+1100 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: state has changed since last snapshot, so incrementing serial to 85
2022-01-04T13:50:09.040+1100 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: writing snapshot at terraform.tfstate
2022-01-04T13:50:09.046+1100 [TRACE] vertex "null_resource.push": visit complete
2022-01-04T13:50:09.046+1100 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "aws_ecs_task_definition.ecs" errored, so skipping
2022-01-04T13:50:09.046+1100 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "null_resource.updatedb" errored, so skipping
2022-01-04T13:50:09.046+1100 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null\"] (close)" errored, so skipping
2022-01-04T13:50:09.047+1100 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "aws_ecs_service.ecs" errored, so skipping
2022-01-04T13:50:09.047+1100 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)" errored, so skipping
2022-01-04T13:50:09.047+1100 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)" errored, so skipping
2022-01-04T13:50:09.047+1100 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "root" errored, so skipping
2022-01-04T13:50:09.047+1100 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: have already backed up original terraform.tfstate to terraform.tfstate.backup on a previous write
2022-01-04T13:50:09.049+1100 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: state has changed since last snapshot, so incrementing serial to 86
2022-01-04T13:50:09.049+1100 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: writing snapshot at terraform.tfstate
╷
│ Error: local-exec provisioner error
│
│   with null_resource.push,
│   on main.tf line 191, in resource "null_resource" "push":
│  191:   provisioner "local-exec" {
│
│ Error running command 'aws ecr get-login-password --region "$region" |
│ docker login --username AWS --password-stdin "$ecr_fqdn"
│ docker tag "servian/techchallengeapp:latest" "$repository"
│ docker push "$repository:latest"
│ docker logout "$ecr_fqdn"
│ ': exit status 1. Output:
│ Provided region_name '"$region"' doesn't match a supported format.
│ Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
│
╵
2022-01-04T13:50:09.053+1100 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: removing lock metadata file .terraform.tfstate.lock.info
2022-01-04T13:50:09.053+1100 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: unlocked by closing terraform.tfstate
2022-01-04T13:50:09.054+1100 [DEBUG] provider.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing"
2022-01-04T13:50:09.054+1100 [DEBUG] provider.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing"
2022-01-04T13:50:09.064+1100 [DEBUG] provider: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null/3.1.0/windows_amd64/terraform-provider-null_v3.1.0_x5.exe pid=38252
2022-01-04T13:50:09.064+1100 [DEBUG] provider: plugin exited
2022-01-04T13:50:09.070+1100 [DEBUG] provider: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/3.70.0/windows_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v3.70.0_x5.exe pid=31016
2022-01-04T13:50:09.070+1100 [DEBUG] provider: plugin exited
```

Ì have checked my AWS region as well

```
    $ aws configure get region
     ap-southeast-2
```

Comment: @EAS Please try to explain why you made an edit rather than promote its supposed usefulness in the edit log.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**:

A `${ ... }` sequence is an interpolation in Terraform's configuration language, which evaluates the expression given between the markers. Unix shells typically use `$..`

As per the [official documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec#command), the `command` is evaluated in a shell, and can use environment variables or Terraform variables. So, basically, what you are trying to achieve should work fundamentally.

I did a quick test and I was able to successfully apply that locally:

with double quotes

```
null_resource.ecr_login: Creating...
null_resource.ecr_login: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.ecr_login (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "aws ecr get-login-password --region \"$region\" | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin \"$ecr_fqdn\"\n"]
null_resource.ecr_login (local-exec): Login Succeeded
null_resource.ecr_login: Creation complete after 2s [id=6191522068151349753]

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Without double quotes:

```
null_resource.ecr_login: Creating...
null_resource.ecr_login: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.ecr_login (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "aws ecr get-login-password --region $region | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $ecr_fqdn\n"]
null_resource.ecr_login (local-exec): Login Succeeded
null_resource.ecr_login: Creation complete after 2s [id=931251830265041579]

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

**Now, let's look at the error you are encountering**:

```
null_resource.push: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.push (local-exec): Executing: ["cmd" "/C" "aws ecr get-login-password --region \"$region\" | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin \"$ecr_fqdn\"\r\ndocker tag \"servian/techchallengeapp:latest\" \"$repository\"\r\ndocker push \"$repository:latest\"\r\ndocker logout \"$ecr_fqdn\"\r\n"]

null_resource.push (local-exec): **Provided region_name '"$region"' doesn't match a supported format.**
null_resource.push (local-exec): Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
2022-01-04T13:50:09.038+1100 [WARN]  Errors while provisioning null_resource.push with "local-exec", so aborting
```

It seems like you are trying to execute these commands on Windows Command Prompt, that too with the quotes and somehow the CMD doesn't know what to do with it. Here's a [similar issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23397).

Anyway, I would recommend doing the regex operation in terraform `locals` block and then simply using terraform native variable and local values.

Something like this:

```
locals{
  ecr_fqdn = regex("^([^/]*)/", aws_ecr_repository.ecs.repository_url.0
}
```

and the `null_resource`:

```
resource "null_resource" "push" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
aws ecr get-login-password --region ${var.region} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${local.ecr_fqdn}
docker tag "servian/techchallengeapp:latest" ${aws_ecr_repository.ecs.repository_url}
docker push "${aws_ecr_repository.ecs.repository_url}:latest"
docker logout ${local.ecr_fqdn}
EOF
  }
  depends_on = [aws_ecr_repository.ecs]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried removing the double quotes it's showing "we can only enclose strings in double quotes". Please find the error below ##################

Comment: @Loki - Alright, I think the updated answer will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks @bhalothia, Yes, as you mentioned CMD isn't recognising the command. It worked when i run the script on my mac.

Comment: @Loki - I'm glad it helped. Please update the question to reflect that it's for CMD so that others can also find it easily. :)